# What does this code output a smiley face?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   string x;
   x = not false and true;

   cout << x << endl;
}
```

Why does this code output a smiley face when ran?

Answer (score 17):

Nothing wrong with the code.

`not false and true` is equivalent to `!false && true` which is `1`.

Then you use `std::string::operator=(char)` to assign the value to `x`. A value of `1` for a `char` apparently translates to a smiley on your system.

Comment: For the record, this code does not compile on MSVC 2010, complaining 'not' and 'and' are not keywords.

Comment: @WilliamCustode: For the record, this is a bug in msvc that is present  since version 2008. Can be fixed by inclusion of 3rdparty headers that define `not`,`and`, etc. According to [boost forums list](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/the-not-keyword-td3865759.html), `#include <ciso646>` should fix it.

Comment: Ahh, good to know. I assumed as much, but couldn't find anything from MS that stated it was a known bug. If it's a standard, you should reference the section of the standard that mentions it.

Comment: @WilliamCustode try with compiler parameter /Za